# Reshaping R dataframe so values of one column are now their own column and grouping by other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

Similar questions like this have been asked but not quite to this extent.  I have a dataframe that has the information like the following

```
location    field    sample    date          height    temp   
loc1        fieldA   1_1       202001        1         86     
loc1        fieldA   1_1       202001        10        92     
loc1        fieldA   2_1       202001        1         88
loc1        fieldA   2_1       202001        10        82
loc1        filedA   1_2       202002        1         81
loc1        fieldA   1_2       202002        10        90
loc1        filedA   2_2       202002        1         88
loc1        filedA   2_2       202002        10        82
```

For every location there are several fields, for each field there are two measurement locations and for each of those locations there are two heights for measurements. For example, in location1 fieldA sample 1_1 refers to the first location and the first sample and there are two heights for this and taken on a certain date. Then there is location1, fieldA sample 1_2 which refers to first location but second sample at a second date. This goes on further with locB and more field names but this is the basic idea

Ideally I need the following

```
location    field   1_1_temp  1_10_temp  2_1_temp    2_10_temp     date
loc1        fieldA  86        92         88          82            202001
loc1        fieldA  81        90         88          82            202002
```

For each location and each field I need a time series of the data.  location1 fieldA will have a time series, location1 fieldB will have a time series, location2 fieldAA will have one and so on. Where 1_1_temp will the first location and height 1, 1_10_temp will be first location at height 10 and so on.  I'm sure I need dplyr and tidy but not sure the extent to how to do this. Something like

```
df <- group_by(location) %>%
       group_by(field) %>%
      mutate()
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide reproducible data with enough diversity to reproduce the issue (eg multiple entries for `location` and `field`).  You can use `dput` or just define an example tibble inline.

Comment: In the column `field`, should not be always `fieldA`? I mean, in your example, so `filedA` is a typo.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I think the new column names (`sample_1_1_temp` and `sample_2_10_temp`) can be broken down into 4 components, all separated by `"_"`. **(1)** The static prefix `"sample"`. **(2)** The dynamic `sample` _index_ — like the `cur_group_id()` generated by `dplyr::group_by(sample)` — which is `1` and `2` respectively for `sample`s `"1_1"` and  `"2_1"`; this indexing would continue through `3` and `4` for `sample`s `"1_2"` and `"2_2"`.  **(3)** The `height` value, which is `1` and `10` respectively.  **(4)** The static suffix `"temp"`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this particular naming convention is inadvisable, since the very structure of the results — the number and taxonomy of the columns — will vary wildly if there is even slight variation in the range and ordering of the data within `sample` or `height`.

Comment: I had to write this quick and I apologize for the lack of clarity and I made a quick edit that hopefully helps.  Each sample is taken at the same spot and height for each location and field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `filedA` is an error, would answer the next code your question?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text = 'location    field    sample    date          height    temp   
loc1        fieldA   1_1       202001        1         86     
loc1        fieldA   1_1       202001        10        92     
loc1        fieldA   2_1       202001        1         88
loc1        fieldA   2_1       202001        10        82
loc1        fieldA   1_2       202002        1         81
loc1        fieldA   1_2       202002        10        90
loc1        fieldA   2_2       202002        1         88
loc1        fieldA   2_2       202002        10        82', header = TRUE)

df %>% 
    mutate(sample = sub("(\\d)_\\d","\\1",sample)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(location, field, date, sample), names_from = c(height), values_from = temp, names_prefix = "sample")
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  location field    date sample sample1 sample10
  <chr>    <chr>   <int> <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 loc1     fieldA 202001 1           86       92
2 loc1     fieldA 202001 2           88       82
3 loc1     fieldA 202002 1           81       90
4 loc1     fieldA 202002 2           88       82
```

**Update after the update of the question:**

```r
df %>% 
    mutate(sample = sub("(\\d)_\\d","\\1",sample)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(location, field, date), names_from = c(sample, height), values_from = temp, names_prefix = "sample") %>% 
    mutate(date = lubridate::ym(as.character(date)))
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  location field  date       sample1_1 sample1_10 sample2_1 sample2_10
  <chr>    <chr>  <date>         <int>      <int>     <int>      <int>
1 loc1     fieldA 2020-01-01        86         92        88         82
2 loc1     fieldA 2020-02-01        81         90        88         82
```

Comment: This seems pretty close to what I need.  I apologize for the confusion as I had to write this fast and did not review as thoroughly as intended.  I made a quick edit that hopefully provides some clarity.  Using the pivot_wider may have been what I was needing

Comment: @user2113499 I updated my answer looking at your desired output

Comment: Thanks! That is a great solution.  I am only mildly familiar with dplyr and tidy right now and did not know about the pivot_wider function. Great to learn about that one!